# Set MS Sql result in variable and reuse it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently my code is something like this.

```
select * 
from tblReq 
where ReqID in (select ReqID from tblLog where LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and LogDate < '2015/05/31')
```

Just wondering how actually the database find the result for this query? Is it re-run every time it ran in sub-query? And is there any script where I can store the list of result in some variable and able to use it back? (below code)

```
select @logs = tblLog.ReqID from tblLog where tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31'  
select * from tblReq where ReqID in (@logs)
```

Comment: Don't  worry, SQL server chooses usually most optimal query plan for single statements. Using any kind of temporary tables or variables makes things often slower (there are exceptions, but not for that simple queries). Look at execution plans in SSMS and decide yourselves :)

Comment: `variable` stores a single value. `temporary table` stores complete table. For iterating (through rows of temporary tables or other) there are `cursors`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can store the result in a variable and reuse it several times later. In your case, it will be a `table variable` as you could have multiple items. Then, simple `join` it to the initial query:

```
DECLARE @Logs TABLE
(
    [LogID] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Logs ([LogID])
Select tblLog.ReqID 
from tblLog 
where tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' 
    and tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31'  

select * 
from tblReq A
INNER JOIN  @Logs L
    ON A.ReqID = L.LogID
```

Also, this could harm your query performance, as table variables are not like `black box` for the query optimizer. If you are storing a large amount of rows, use `temporary` tables instead in order to use parallel execution plans.

Comment: +1 This is the approach I'd go for normally. However, I'd probably not join to the table but use it like; `WHERE ReqID IN (SELECT LogID FROM @Logs)`. I'd do that purely from a readability perspective though, and not from a performance perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`view`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864(v=sql.105).aspx) if you want to refer to your query later

```
CREATE VIEW V1 AS
SELECT tblLog.ReqID
FROM tblLog
WHERE tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' 
AND tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31'
```

Per to the comment below, you can use a `table valued function` as well

```
CREATE FUNCTION functionName(@start DATE, @end DATE)
RETURNS @result TABLE 
(
    ReqID INT NOT NULL
)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT @result
        SELECT tblLog.ReqID
        FROM tblLog
        WHERE tblLog.LogDate >= @start 
        AND tblLog.LogDate < @end
    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: There is no point at all to create such view, as it could be re-written to `in-line` function (parametrized view) accepting `start` and `end` date as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For your case.. best solution is to use a join

The best (which will work even in complex cases) it includes a query as table(tblLog)

```
select * from tblReq join (select logid from tbllog where 
tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31')tblLog
on tblReq.ReqID=tblLog.ReqID
```

Or simple

```
select * from tblReq join tblLog on tblReq.ReqID=tblLog.ReqID where 
tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31'
```

Or simpler: Also you can use subquery (subquery is simpler but cases slow performance if gets too many results)

```
select * from tblReq where ReqID in (select tblLog.ReqID from tblLog where 
tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and
tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31')
```

If you must have to store because you use it many times in same process then

```
craete TABLE #logs
(
    [LogID] INT
);
insert into #logs select tblLog.ReqID from tblLog where 
tblLog.LogDate >= '2015/04/01' and
tblLog.LogDate < '2015/05/31'

select * from tblReq where ReqID in (select logid from #logs) // or use join
```

**Important**

`variable` stores a single value. temporary table stores `complete table`. For iterating (through rows of temporary tables or other) there are `cursors`. However try to use