# How to set SQL Server query result in variable(Global) and reuse it?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30432402/set-ms-sql-result-in-variable-and-reuse-it)  solution, but didn't work if you want to query one by one!

Code:

```
Declare @ID int;

SET @ID = SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM Students 

// After that query is ran I will run this query 
SELECT * 
FROM Courses AS C 
WHERE C.studentID = @ID 

// These above queries aren't great way to query it,
// but I am just trying to illustrate what I am trying to achieve
```

It works fine and stores the result of that query in

> @ID

temporarily if these two queries are ran together, which I don't want to do.

Is there any way we can hold the value in the variable? Like running first query and store the ID in the variable, then run second query.

I know we can do it in a stored procedure, but I wanted to know if we can do in query window!

Thank you

Comment: What you are trying to save? second approach will work rite?   
 select TOP(1) @ID =  ID from yourtable

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MSSQL server does not have a concept of global variables so you cannot
run first query and store the ID in the variable, then run second query.

If you store it in a variable like shown above it will only last till the query is completed.

If you want to be available to the current query window no matter what query you execute it there are multiple ways to do it.

1)Select it into a temp table(#tablename) and it is available in the current query window

2)select it into global temp table(##tablename) and it is available to the current session

3)one other way to make it available to the current session it to store it in a context info and then retreive it.
For your purpose #table seems the more appropriate option.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to know if there is a concept of global variable or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
Declare @ID int;
select TOP(1) @ID =  ID from Students
--select @id
Select * from Courses as C where C.studentID = @ID
```

Comment: Yaa I can, but I didn't want to run it together. Thank you for your help to :D

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server variables are meant to work in single batch. So complete code having variables must be executed all at once.